# How do I mark an issue as closed on Azure Boards?

Tags: azure-devops

How do I mark an issue as closed after I complete it?

The status says 'Development hasn't started' because I don't see a way to change the status of that to 'In Progress'.

It tells me something called Create a Branch, which I don't use. I am a single person developer, and even though the project will be open source, I only have a master branch.

Is there a way to mark it as completed? I have the code checked in, all I want to do now is mark it as closed and move on to my next issue.

Why isn't the status just a Drop Down I can set?

Comment: I figured it out, you have to change the State to Closed.

Comment: You might consider using the User Story and Bugs convention. Bugs can be managed as individual work items or as "tasks" for a User Story. Managing bugs as tasks causes them to be shown alongside Tasks in the sprint task board, or as a list of check boxes under the story on the team backlog board. For items that come in as issues found in prod, we have created a new work item type that is just a user story that goes by a different name and has a different icon. These settings are found in the Organization settings under _Process_.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the issue status.  The field you are describing is called "State".

The Development field will show you links to commits, branches, or pull requests.  You will have to associate the work item to them.

If you don't want to see this field to avoid confusion, you can [customize the process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#add-or-modify-a-field) to hide this area on the work item.